# Initializing objects in .net?

Tags: c#

```
public class Test 
{
    //Car c = null; // Is this better and is it good to set it to null.

    public void A()
    {
        Car c = new Car();
    }

    public void B()
    {
        Car c = new Car();
    }

    public void C()
    {
        Car c = new Car();
    }
}
```

1)  Can I just declare Object 0 globally at the top and use it in each method instead of creating a new one each time (Is this what I am actually doing?)

2)  Is it a good idea to initially set the object to null?

Comment: Please revisit your code and post something that compiles.

Comment: I quickly updated my code, don't know why this was downvoted.  The main question is not about null, but mainly if re-declaration of objects will add to the size of my executable.

Comment: You should come back and take your time. You now have three local variables, none of which refer to the `c` class member object.

Comment: I commented out the c class member object to show I am not using it.  If I had it declared, I would remove the local variables and just do something c = new Car();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FxCop states that you should avoid unnecessary initialising code, because it generates unnecessary IL, which affects performance.  (Although I think that the performance hit is very minimal).
Sometimes, I also explicitly initialize variables, just to make my code more clear.

To answer your first question: it's all a matter of what you're trying / wanting to do ...

Comment: Thanks, this was the type of answer I was looking for.  It seemed redundant to keep initializing the same object over and over again. Thanks again.

Comment: yeah, my C and C++ days make me initialize references to null, although I know it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question and has been asked many times on SO. The answer is, "it's a matter of style". Some prefer a style that indicates understanding of the fact that the compiler will initialize to null. Others prefer a style that makes it unnecessary to understand that the compiler will initialize to null.

Comment: That was part of my question.

Comment: Does re-declaration of objects increase the size of my executable or affect performance if I do it many times.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Can I just declare Object 0 globally at the top and use it in each method instead of creating a new one each time (Is this what I am actually doing?)

Apart from the invalid name for an object (compare `0` and `O`), yes, you can. Redeclaring creates *another* variable with local scope, it does not modify the private member of the class.

> 2) Is it a good idea to initially set the object to null?

It’s unnecessary since this is done automatically when an object of your class is created.

Comment: The invalid names come from me typing to fast.

Comment: Does redeclaration of objects add to the size of the executable?

Comment: Of course it does, a redaclaration creates a new (local) variable, wich of course needs to be saved.